# Dynamically add the menu based on session value in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am working on a project where i have to show different menu based on username
i have added the menu in master page 
The code is

```
         <ul  id="ul_myLst" runat="server">
               <li><a href="Testimonials.aspx">Testimonial</a></li>

           <li><a href="About_us.aspx">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="Registration.aspx">Registartion</a></li>

               <li id="student" runat="server" visible="false">
                   <a href="Profile">profile</a>
                   <ul>
                       <li>
                       <a href="Profile">View profile</a>
                        </li>
                       <li>
                       <a href="Profile">Edit profile</a>
                        </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>

              <li id="abc" runat="server" visible="false" ><a href="Data.aspx">Admin</a></li>
              <li id="Li1" runat="server" visible="false" ><a href="Reports.aspx">Reports</a></li>

           </ul>
```

where i want to show three hidden

value when user logged in as "admin"

here is my .cs code

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["UserName"] as string))
    {

        admin();
    }

}
private void admin()
{
   if (Session["UserName"].ToString() == "admin")
   {
       HtmlGenericControl ul = (HtmlGenericControl)(this.FindControl("abc"));
       ul.Style["visibility"] = "visible";
   }
}
```

This code is not giving me any error but it's also not showing me the desired output..

Answer (score 0):

You can hide and show it this way:

```
ul.Style.Add("visibility","visible"); // for showing
ul.Style.Add("display","block");
```

and for hiding:

```
ul.Style.Add("visibilty","hidden"); // for hiding
ul.Style.Add("display","none");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display` property :

```
ul.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Since your control has an `id` and `runat="server"`, you may also use :

```
abc.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

`visible="false"` does not touch an element's style at all. This is setting the `Control.Visible` property of the control you are manipulating. When this property is set to false, the control is not rendered to the page at all - it is just absent on the final markup. So on the server side you actually want this in `admin` method:

```
ul.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["UserName"] as string))
        {

            admin();
        }

    }
    private void admin()
    {
        if (Session["UserName"].ToString() == "admin")
        {
            this.Page.FindControl("abc").Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

If you use in Master  page then use this code

```
private void admin()
    {
        if (Session["UserName"].ToString() == "admin")
        {
            this.Master.FindControl("abc").Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

thanks